# asp.net core/angular4 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ApplicationRef

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

Trying to use angular4 for asp.net core project.

Using this repo https://github.com/cadabloom/AspNetCoreAngular for angular tempating.

Don't know what causes it and is there a way to get more detail about this error types?

Getting this error.

```
vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:83954 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ApplicationRef! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for ApplicationRef!
    at injectionError (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:12189)
    at noProviderError (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:12227)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13728)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13767)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13699)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13568)
    at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:14495)
    at NgModuleFactory.create (vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:14468)
    at vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:15709 Error: No provider for ApplicationRef!
    at injectionError (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:12189:86)
    at noProviderError (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:12227:12)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13728:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13767:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13699:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:13568:21)
    at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:122:51)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:14495:76)
    at NgModuleFactory.create (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:14468:18)
    at http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=8G5nuphpleAMB8hDVj0v8l9es64guglhqGWIwYdey3M:15709:61
```

home.components.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { PromoSliderComponent } from './promoslider.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: '/home.component.html'
})

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],  
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [],
    imports: [PromoSliderComponent],
    schemas: []
})

export class HomeComponent {

}
```

promoslidercomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'promo-slider',
    templateUrl: './promoslider.component.html'
})
export class PromoSliderComponent {
}
```

app.module.shared.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { PromoSliderComponent } from './components/home/promoslider.component';


export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        PromoSliderComponent,
        HomeComponent

    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]) 
    ],
};
```

addp.module.client.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
//import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
//import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

question 2:using angular in asp.net core project obligate me to use component instead of partials. is there a way to use partials with angular? i dont want to get all data from services or do i have to?